# Elasticsearch 5.2.2 with StackOverflowError

Tags: elasticsearch, stack-overflow

I am using elasticsearch 5.2.2 with single node, the memory is 16GB. Some processes write contents to elasticsearch, but meet such error:

```
[2017-10-05T21:57:41,550][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataUpdateSettingsService] [node1] updating number_of_replicas to [0] for indices [abc_ef]
[2017-10-05T21:57:41,551][INFO ][o.e.c.s.IndexScopedSettings] [node1] updating [index.refresh_interval] from [1s] to [-1]
[2017-10-05T21:57:41,551][INFO ][o.e.c.s.IndexScopedSettings] [node1] updating [index.refresh_interval] from [1s] to [-1]
[2017-10-05T21:57:41,677][ERROR][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [node1] fatal error in thread [elasticsearch[node1][bulk][T#9]], exiting java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.contains(Collections.java:1032) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.contains(Collections.java:1032) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.contains(Collections.java:1032) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.contains(Collections.java:1032) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.contains(Collections.java:1032) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.contains(Collections.java:1032) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.contains(Collections.java:1032) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.contains(Collections.java:1032) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.contains(Collections.java:1032) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.contains(Collections.java:1032) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.contains(Collections.java:1032) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.contains(Collections.java:1032) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.contains(Collections.java:1032) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.contains(Collections.java:1032) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.contains(Collections.java:1032) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.contains(Collections.java:1032) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
```

Comment: what are these processes doing on ES? Are you using bulk apis? Give some more details in question

Comment: yes, the process use bulk apis to insert and update the index, it runs well for about 5 days but stackoverflow error happened.

Comment: post this error on elasticsearch's official discussion forum along with full stack trace. Somebody will come back there.